# callback error, when trying to call a function in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, websocket, raspberry-pi, distance, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am trying to control a raspberry pi through web socket. I found a similar project and have been building my project around it. I have managed to get everything except a distance sensor working.

```
tank.getDistance = function () {
   async.parallel([
    gpio.write(trig,0),
    gpio.write(trig,1),
    gpio.write(trig,0),
  ]);
  var start,stop;
  while(gpio.read(echo) == 0){start = Date.now();}
  while(gpio.read(echo) == 1){stop = Date.now();}
  var distance = ((stop-start)/1000.0)*17000
  console.log("distance: "+ distance);
};
```

this is how i am trying to read from the ultrasonic sensor. I have tested this logic in python and it was working there.

```
socket.on('keydown', function (dir) {
    switch (dir) {
      case 'up':
        tank.moveForward();
        console.log("forward");
        tank.getDistance();
        break;
...
```

this is where i call the function. But every time I call this function, I get a

```
/home/pi/marinaBot/marinaBot/node_modules/rpi-gpio/rpi-gpio.js:286
            throw new Error('A callback must be provided')
            ^
Error: A callback must be provided
    at Gpio.read.input (/home/pi/marinaBot/marinaBot/node_modules/rpi-gpio/rpi-gpio.js:286:19)
    at Object.tank.getDistance (/home/pi/marinaBot/marinaBot/app.js:78:14)
```

not sure why this is occurring as I am not returning anything. I have tried using other ultrasonic libraries like "r-pi-usonic" but I dont understand the setup of it.
Any Ideas?
Just starting to learn NodeJS. this may be something realluy simple.

Comment: async.parallel(items, cb) - expects you to send a callback as the second parameter, also all the logic should be done there, or if you don't like callback approach you can switch to Promises it is cleaner in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gpio.read(echo, callbackfunction(error, data){})
```

Please check this document

https://github.com/JamesBarwell/rpi-gpio.js#readchannel-callback

---

You need `async/await` function for `while`

```
var gpio = require('rpi-gpio')

var gpio_read = function (channel) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        gpio.read(channel, function (error, result) {
            console.log('gpio.read', error, result);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

var echo = 16;

var calculateDistance = async function () {
    var start, stop;

    while (await gpio_read(echo) == false) { start = Date.now(); }
    while (await gpio_read(echo) == true) { stop = Date.now(); }
    var distance = ((stop - start) / 1000.0) * 17000
    console.log("distance: " + distance);
}

gpiop.setup(echo, gpio.DIR_IN)
    .then(function () {
        calculateDistance();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error: ', err.toString())
    })
```

**Updated content:**
1.  Created `calculateDistance` function with `async` as

```
  var calculateDistance = async function () { ... }
```

2. `return new Promise`

Comment: how would i write a call back function. in the docs, write also wants a callback but in my case it works without any.

Comment: Of course, write function can work without callback, because We can ignore wrte success

Comment: thanks but i m not sure how do i link everything up?

Comment: gpio.read null false is the error i m getting using the modded code

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: I updated my answer with `working`, I tested on my raspberry pi.  my node version is `v8.11.1`